# Gawk and GNU Parallel to a single file?

Tags: awk, gawk, gnu-parallel

Using the following script with Gawk 4.1 to convert and combine multiple source files into fewer csv files based on a date column within, I am attempting to use GNU Parallel to speed things along:

```
BEGIN { FS="-"; OFS="," }
{
    gsub(/\|/, ",", $7)  # pipe to csv
    gsub(/,[^0-9]|,$/, ",0", $7)  # null measures to zero
    print $1"-"$2"-"$3" "$4":00", $5, $6, $7 >> "out_" $1 $2 $3 ".csv"
}
```

However the output lines are getting combined in strange ways, with field values partially combined. I have tried combinations of the Parallel options --group, --lb and -k, with no success.

Is there an approach with Gawk and Parallel where I can safely have multiple Awks writing to files concurrently?

Same issue also occurs with Mawk v1.3.4

Comment: I don't see anything to do with `parallel` in your code...

Comment: If all the `awk` processes run in parallel and write to the same output files, you are bound to get a mess. Could you write to output files whose names are prefixed with the `parallel` job number and then combine them at the end with `cat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am alluding to a solution along these lines in my comment:

```
parallel gawk -v job={#} -f ./script.awk {} ::: *.csv
```

where `script.awk` contains the following elements in addition to your logic:

```
BEGIN{out="out_" job "-a-b-c.csv"; print out}
```

**Output**

```
out_1-a-b-c.csv
out_2-a-b-c.csv
out_3-a-b-c.csv
out_4-a-b-c.csv
```

Comment: This led me to {%} for the slot: "Job slot number. This replacement string will be replaced by the job's slot number between 1 and number of jobs to run in parallel. There will never be 2 jobs running at the same time with the same job slot number." - Thanks for the pointer!